# Knockout get object from observableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have an observableArray in my Knockout app and I'm wondering how I can go about selecting only the targeted object within the array.

I have the following code which calculates the total of all 'value's within the array but I'd like to be able to just select, say, only the second 'value' within the array.

```
self.csu_treatment_inputs = ko.observableArray([
                {
                    value: ko.observable(10),
                    image: ko.observable('')
                },
                {
                    value: ko.observable(120),
                    image: ko.observable('')
                },
                {
                    value: ko.observable(160),
                    image: ko.observable('')
                },

            ]);

self.totaltest = ko.computed(function () {
            var total = 0;
            ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.value_inputs(), function (item) {
                  total += parseFloat(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(item.value));
            });
            return total;
    });
```

Comment: I've managed to solve this by adding an ID to each object in the array and then wrap my total function around an 'if' statement. I'm wondering though if there's a cleaner way to do this without manually having to assign an ID to each object in the array?

Comment: What do you mean "select"? You want to bind something to the "second value" (for example)?

Comment: Yes. Example: I want to be able to get the value from second object only. In a normal array I'd just use array[1].value etc, but doing this with knockout returns an undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bind to the second value, use this code:

```
<span data-bind='text: csu_treatment_inputs()[1].value'></span>
```

Exemple:
http://jsfiddle.net/v6T5T/

If you want to access an element from javascript, use this:

```
total+= parseFloat(self.test_values()[i].value());
```

Exemple: http://jsfiddle.net/v6T5T/2/

Comment: I want to be able to bind the second (or x) value inside the javascript, it's no use to me doing this inside the HTML

Comment: It's the same code in the js: `yourarray()[1].value`